binance webhook signal conflict
// Uzun giriş
if (longEntry and canOpenLong)
    strategy.close("Short")
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    canOpenLong := false
    canOpenShort := true
    

// Kısa giriş
if (shortEntry and canOpenShort) 
    strategy.close("Long")
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    canOpenShort := false
    canOpenLong := true     

long closing and short signals come at the same time, Binance is making one of them. how do i fix it

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

var bool canOpenShort = true

var bool longClosed = false
var bool shortClosed = false

// Uzun giriş
if (longEntry and canOpenLong and not longClosed)
   strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
   canOpenLong := false
   canOpenShort := true
   longClosed := true

// Uzun çıkış
if (not longEntry and longClosed)
   strategy.close("Long")
   longClosed := false
   canOpenLong := true

// Kısa giriş
if (shortEntry and canOpenShort and not shortClosed) 
   strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
   canOpenShort := false
   canOpenLong := true
   shortClosed := true

// Kısa çıkış
if (not shortEntry and shortClosed)
   strategy.close("Short")
   shortClosed := false
   canOpenShort := true

ı fix it

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
